# laravel 5.6 related models to related models

Tags: php, laravel-5, base-de-datos, eloquent, model

Tengo en el modelo *Finca.php*

```
public function piscinas(){
    return $this->hasMany(Piscina::class)->select('id' , 'finca_id', 'area' , 'name');
}
```

Y en el modelo *Piscina.php*

```
public function finca(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Finca::class);
}

public function planificacion(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Planificacion::class);
}
```

**¿Como podria traerme las piscinas de una finca que no tengan planificacion?**

```
$finca->piscinas->no_contains_planificacion???
```

Comment: ¿Tu modelo *Piscina* tiene un campo `planificacion_id?

Comment: no tiene, ya que la piscina puede estar sin planificacion

Comment: y si sí tiene planificacion, ¿como la guardas entonces?

Comment: se crea un registro en la tabla planificacion con piscina_id

Comment: Entonces una planificacion pertenece solo a una piscina?

Comment: una piscina tiene una sola planificacion... al hacer una consulta a la tabla planificaciones contiene las planificaciones de todas las piscinas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta con esto en tu modelo *Finca*. Haz un `leftJoin` con `planificacion` y ahi validas si el campo `piscina_id` es `null`

```
return $this->hasMany(DB::table('piscina'))
   ->leftJoin('planificacion', 'planificacion.piscina_id', '=', 'piscina.id')
   ->select('piscina.id' , 'piscina.finca_id', 'piscina.area' , 'piscina.name')
   ->whereNull('planificacion.piscina_id')
   ->get();
```

---

Infórmate más sobre el Query Builder de Laravel en su [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)

Comment: arroja el siguiente error: ErrorException (E_ERROR)
Type error: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::__construct(), 0 passed

Comment: solventado de la siguiente manera

return $this->hasMany(Piscina::class)
   ->leftJoin('planificacion', 'planificacion.piscina_id', '=', 'piscina.id')
   ->select('piscina.id' , 'piscina.finca_id', 'piscina.area' , 'piscina.name')
   ->whereNull('planificacion.piscina_id')
   ->get();

Comment: como puedo darle +1 a tu solucion? tengo menso de 15 reputacion? muchas gracias, eres un crack

Comment: No te preocupes, estamos para ayudar, me alegro que te haya servido ;)

Comment: Ahora necesito traerme todas las piscinas de la finca que tengan planificacion... aun mi logica no me da muy bien para esto, disculpa el abuso si podras ayudarme por favor

Comment: Simplemente cambia el `whereNull` por `whereNotNull`. Editaré mi respuesta para ponerte ahí los links de la documentación de laravel, como que de paso aprendes más ;)

Comment: muchas gracias amigo... exitos!

Comment: De nada, suerte!

Comment: estoy usando softdeletes y funciona muy bien con Eloquent, pero en los query result hecho con query builder siguen apareciendo asi esten trashed o no trashed.

It is not clear in the current docs of Laravel , but seeing that the concept of soft deleting just appears under Eloquent ORM - Soft Deleting and not under Query Builder, we can only assume that: soft delete only works with Eloquent ORM.

Comment: Puedes agregar un where más donde filtres los que tienen el campo deleted_at como null, asi: `->whereNull('planificacion.deleted_at')`.

Comment: agregando el where funciona para para traerme a las piscina que tienen planificacion, pero una vez que se le haya eliminado la planificacion y quiero volver a asignarle una planificacion, no me aparece

Comment: Bueno no te entiendo muy bien, si ya la eliminaste mediante softdeletes, se puede recuperar. En todo caso formula una nueva pregunta, como que así especificas más a detalle

Comment: gracias, replanteado en otra pregunta mi problema